# How to implement AutoCompleteTextView with several chosen options?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap-3, android-edittext

Web application which uses Bootstrap, has input area like this.

[image]

Is there any library to implement EditText like this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the completed bubbles are called "chips" in Android. A full example of a working solution is far too detailed for an answer here, but this is just one library that I have used with success.

https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/

And one more, for safe measure

https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

Answer (score 0):

Use `AutoCompleteTextView`

Offical example:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html